# En WHILE: Boolean cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java

Error al hacer el equal del boolean seguir en el while.

**boolean cannot be dereferenced**

```
boolean seguir = false;
do{
/*Aquí hay un juego... y pregunta si quiere seguir jugando*/
seguir = Character.toUpperCase(volverjugar.charAt(0))=='S' ;  
} while ( seguir.equals(true) );
```

Comment: Para compara booleanos simplemente tienes que preguntar asi: while( seguir == true) o mejor aun asi: while( seguir )

Comment: jaja! Maravilloso el while(seguir)

Comment: me alegra que te haya servido. Marca mi respuesta como que solucionó tu problema. Gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tienes un error en la siguiente línea:

```
while (seguir.equals(true));
```

Estás intentando comparar un `boolean` como un `String`

---

Lo correcto sería:

```
while ( seguir ); //mientras sea true, hace lo que contiene la sentencia do
```

Cuando `seguir`, sea `false`, rompe el ciclo

Answer (score 2):

Para comparar booleanos debes comparar de la siguiente manera:

```
while(seguir == true)
```

o mejor aun asi:

```
while(seguir)
```

Espero te haya ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Independientemente de que no necesitas utilizar el método `equals()` para comparar buleanos, estás llamando un método sobre un tipo primitivo.

```
boolean seguir = false;// esta variable es de un tipo primitivo no un objeto
...
while ( seguir.equals(true) );// por tanto esta llamada de error de compilación
```

Como te han comentado ya, solo necesitas hacer esto: `while (seguir)`. Pero si quires, por el motivo que sea, hacer uso del método `equals()` debes declarar la variable como `Boolean` en vez de `boolean`: `Boolean seguir = false;`